# What is the best practise to create a notification services such as in facebook website?

Tags: facebook, http, notifications

What is the best practise to create a notification services such as in facebook website. I see it is noy good to make a http request periodically to check if there is updates on the server or not.

Comment: What server side language do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This is calling long polling (type of an AJAX).

I'll try to describe a situation where you use PHP and JS, as Facebook does.

- You send an AJAX request to the server.
- Infinite loop starts on the server side

```
<?php 
$seconds = 0;
while(true) {
   if ($seconds >= 55) {
        die("no_notifications");
   }
   if (false !== ($notifications_json = getNotifications()) {
        echo $notifications_json;
        die();
   }
   $seconds++;
   sleep($TIME_TO_WAIT_BEFORE_NEXT_CHECK); //this number should be based on your performance 
}
?>
```

- When there's a new notification, script *die()* s and response is handled by javascript
- New request is sent to the server, again, waiting to new notifications

With javascript (I'll show you an example with jQuery), you can use something like

```
$(function() {
   pollForNotifications();   
});

function pollForNotifications() {
   $.get("/notifications", function(response) {
         if (response != "no_notifications") {
             alert("You've got one new notification!");
             //more proccessing here
         }
         pollForNotifications();
   });
}
```

Remember that there are time limits in specific browsers to complete the request! You SHOULD `die()` after some amount of time (55 seconds) even if you don't have any notifications, to prevent troubles (this prevention is included in script above)!

Comment: @AdhamEnaya: Once on the page load (or when you need to start polling for notifications) and after script dies (when user gets the request)

Comment: @AdhamEnaya: added a jQuery example to make it even easier for you

Comment: I mean, I want to check the notifications for every 10 sec for example!. that's mean every client will have about 6 request per min .. guess there are 1000 concurrent users , so will be 6000 request per min. do you think it's a good for server to receive such a huge increasing number of requests ?!!!!

Comment: @AdhamEnaya: the answer describes how to create only one request per one minute. Take a look at it ;) That's exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WebSocket api for a real push service (not ajax polling). But it is part of HTML5 and not supported by all browsers and web servers at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Pusher](http://www.pusher.com). It'll handle pushing notifications and supports many browsers.